# Java GUI - Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: java, user-interface, error-handling

Now before you mark this as a duplicate - hear me out. I have already looked at the 2 other questions that are similar.

Since this is a GUI Java program, it varies from user to user, and in my specific case, I'm only trying to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius with absolutely no other functions.

Here's my code:

```
package my.tempconvert;

public class TempConvertUI extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    public TempConvertUI() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Farenheit = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Celsius = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        CalcButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Farenheit");

        Farenheit.setText("Insert Farenheit Value");
        Farenheit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                FarenheitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Celsius");

        Celsius.setText("Celsius Will Appear Here");

        CalcButton.setText("Calculate");
        CalcButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CalcButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(Farenheit)
                    .addComponent(Celsius, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 149, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(0, 183, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(CalcButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(Farenheit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Celsius, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(CalcButton)
                .addGap(0, 205, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    private void FarenheitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    }                                         

    private void CalcButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
         float num1, result;

    num1 = Float.parseFloat(Farenheit.getText());

    result = (((float) 5/9) * (num1 - 32));

    Celsius.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }                                          

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TempConvertUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TempConvertUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TempConvertUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TempConvertUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TempConvertUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton CalcButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Celsius;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Farenheit;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

There are no syntax errors - only one output error which is that:

**:Celsius is always outputted as 0.0 or -0.0**
- SOLVED -

Obviously there is something wrong with my code, and I need help on figuring out what that is.

If someone believes that my question is not clear or I haven't followed the guidelines on posting a question, I will gladly take that criticism into account and we can all move forward.

Comment: You have an integer division issue, `5/9` = `0`, try using `5/(float)9` or `5/9f` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast 5/9 to a Float, otherwise it's evaluated as an integer and is automatically set to 0.

Comment: Casting the result of 5/9 will still yield a truncated result. You need to cast *one of the operands.*

Answer (score 1):

It's because the result of `(5/9)` is evaluated as an integer, so its value is zero since it only takes the values at the left side of the dot (e.g. 0.0557 -> 0), you should cast it to float like so:

```
num1 = Float.parseFloat(Farenheit.getText());

result = (((float) 5/9) * (num1 - 32));

Celsius.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: I can't upvote or accept answers yet, but I will as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't cast 5/9, it casts the 5. Correct answer, but not for the reason given.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = ((5/9) * (num1 - 32));
```

Usual integer truncation problem. Also redundant parentheses.

```
result = 5*(num1-32)/9.0;
```